# How to work with Kerberos in python with multiple users?

Tags: python, token, kerberos

Kerberos has always been quite difficult to integrate in software pieces that don't use java/C, but in python it's the weirdest. It uses the systemwide ticket file (so you cant communicate with multiple identities on same isolated machine simultaneously). So far I found KRB5CCNAME variable and overriding it while running in forked subprocess.Popen (along with kinit command line calls via same subprocess.Popen), but this Frankenstein solution is nothing close to what is expected. How to do it smart way while avoiding using terminal calls? There's no way that this mature tech doesn't have proper api for wide use.

Update: Thanks a lot for python-gssapi recommendation, most of problems are resolvable by this library wrapper. Documentation really lacks real world examples tho. + I'm still looking for ways to create keytabs without ktutil or utilize existing ccache with ticket without having keytab.

Comment: Which python library are you using? I recommend python-gssapi. There are others too. I've never seen one that does anything out of the ordinary in terms of tickets.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not even trying anything difficult. Just get the ticket for specific user (out of 1000 others, on same microservice), do the work, end the process. Usually it means basic web APIs with pykerberos/requests-kerberos or Hadoop Web API libs (python-yarn-api, hdfscli, ranger, etc). I will check the python-gssapi, tho it seems like just a non-intuitive wrapper over C Kerberos libs